# Google APK release error, "It is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels in range 9-19 to API levels in range 20+"

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to release v5 of an Android app on Google and get the message,

This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
It is forbidden that a device upgrading from API levels in range 9-19 to API levels in range 20+ should downgrade from version 5 to version 4, which would occur when ...

What does this error mean, and how do we solve it?  The programmer says the code has not changed regarding the api level since version 4 of the app was released last October.

Comment: Can you please post the complete message if possible?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that version 5 is compatible with API 9-19 implying that any users on those API levels will get version 5. However, when those users upgrade to API 20+, it appears the your version 5 is *not* compatible with those devices, meaning the user will suddenly only be eligible for version 4 of your app. As you cannot downgrade versions, you're getting an error.

Make sure your version 5 does not contain a `maxSdkVersion` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Or, if you are using multiple APKs, you should also upload the API 20+ compatible version with a version of at least `6`.

Comment: Awesome, "Make sure your version 5 does not contain a `maxSdkVersion` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`" Yes it did and I removed it and it solved the problem.